# Software and Updates not running

Tags: update-manager

I get this message on terminal when I type `/usr/bin/update-manager`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 890, in _find_spec
AttributeError: 'DynamicImporter' object has no attribute 'find_spec'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/update-manager", line 28, in <module>
    from gi.repository import Gtk
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/importer.py", line 127, in find_module
    'introspection typelib not found' % namespace)
ImportError: cannot import name Gtk, introspection typelib not found.
```

And when I typed 
`software-properties-gtk`, I got this message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 890, in _find_spec
AttributeError: 'DynamicImporter' object has no attribute 'find_spec'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/software-properties-gtk", line 37, in <module>
    from softwareproperties.gtk.SoftwarePropertiesGtk import SoftwarePropertiesGtk
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/gtk/SoftwarePropertiesGtk.py", line 40, in <module>
    from gi.repository import GObject, Gdk, Gtk, Gio, GLib
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/importer.py", line 127, in find_module
    'introspection typelib not found' % namespace)
ImportError: cannot import name Gdk, introspection typelib not found
```

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? Do you have any Python-related PPAs in the system?

Comment: 16.04. Do you have any Python-related PPAs in the system? yes